# Android NavigationDrawer Icon

Tags: android, uinavigationbar, navigation-drawer

I just install Android Studio 1.2.2 and create project by default and pick to create activity with NavigationDrawer
but it looks like? i watch some video tutorial it's should look like 2nd image but on my project it's become 1st image?

what should i do? how to make my activity with navigationdrawer looks like 2nd image?

1st image[image: navigationdrawer icon]
a

2nd image [image]

Comment: Use the sample they give you in Android Studio.. best example for this.. or you can get it from here... http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/  .. follow it and solve the problem ..by yourself...

Answer (score 0):

```
    ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.drawer, R.string.app_name,
            R.string.app_name) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onDrawerStateChanged(newState);
        }

    };
```

Pass the your image instead  of R.drawable.drawer

Comment: i dont get what you mean.. my code just like your code... but new ActionBarDrawerToggle is deprected.. and i check R.drawable.drawer the icon image is same with navigation on 2nd image